# Trigonometric Partial Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, partial-derivative

I need to find

$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial U} \text{ and } \frac{\partial Z}{\partial V}$$

for a $z=f(x,y) = \cos(xy) + y\cos(x)$.

After a bit of an internet search, I think I have found the correct way to obtain a partial derivative for a trigonometric function but I am not so sure at the same time.

Would someone be able to confirm if

$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial U} = -y\sin(xy) - y\sin(x)$$

And as

$$\ x=u^2+v$$ and $$y=u-v^2$$ would $$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial U} =-y\sin[(u^2-u)(u-v^2)] - y\sin(u^2+v)$$

Which would equal $$\ -y\sin(u^3-uv+v^2+v^2u^2) - y\sin(u^2+v)$$

Any help is appreiciated and warmly recieved! I think once I understand how to find 
$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial U}$$ I will be able to find $$  \frac{\partial Z}{\partial V}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For change of variables $(x,y) \to (u,v)$, the chain rule is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}
&= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}
&= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{align}
$$

Details in chapter 2 [here](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~nsjones/ee2mafmv2.pdf)

Comment: Brilliant stuff! Very much appreciated!

Comment: That is probably from Leibniz. Not sure.